# What's in my mystery box?

Tags: kitchens, alarm

I recently moved into a new house, and as part of trying to understand (at a basic level) how everything is wired and plumbed together I've come across a metal box, on the wall of my kitchen. What is likely to be in it, and how can I get in to check? None of my tools seem to be able to open the 'screws'.

My kitchen has been converted from the garage. It's not clear how long the box has been there. It might be from when it was a garage.

I've been searching for the control unit of the house alarm, but not found it yet. Could it be in the box, and is that why it's metal and hard to get into?

[image: Mystery metal box]

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Given the proximity sensor immediately adjacent, I'd assume that it contains your security system. Like Kris said, #2 square drive is most likely. Open 'er up!

Comment: Would love to see the results !

Comment: Can you open it, and post a photo of the contents? Then we might be able to tell you what's in it. A stripped [screw extractor tool](https://www.amazon.com/Damaged-Remover-Extractor-Product-Stop/dp/B00MZCEBII) should be able to get the screws out. Unless those are rivets, in which case you'll have to drill them out.

Comment: I managed to get the bottom screw out today, but I'm still struggling with the top one. I'll have another go later in the week and hopefully post a follow up photo.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to be a #2 square head driver. The box looks to be <strike>PVC</strike> metal from the edge overhang and probably contains branch circuits for the kitchen.  Or could be something different like a housing for low voltage cables.

Comment: Looks like sheet metal to me (in the full-res view), but yeah.